# Angular 8: Optimizar *ngFor cuando se actualiza datos

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io

entorno:
Verión de angular: 8.3.23
Veresión socket.io: 3.2.0

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en tiempo real con socket.io y tengo una lista con

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let ob of objetos">{{ob.tiempo}}<mat-list-item>
```

la cual produce la siguiente pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo bien cuando tengo enlistado unos 30 item, pero cuando tengo en la lista (this.objetos) unos 500 la aplicación se pone lenta mas que todo cuando se utiliza en dispositivo movil, se nota cuando se congela un poco la pantalla cuando se le da click, y eso sucede porque utilizo socket.io y actualizo datos especificos del array `this.objetos` **porque el socket manda una cantidad de datos por segundo bastante considerable**, de esta forma actualizo la data de la imagen anterior

```
public objetos: any[] = [];


ngOnInit() {
   this.wsService.listen('actualizar-tiempo').subscribe((data: any) => {
       for (const d of data) {
          const ob = this.objetos.find((o)=> o.id === d.id);
          if (ob) {
             ob.tiempo = d.tiempo
          }
       }  
   }
}
```

IMPORTANTE: **la cantidad de datos que envía el socket io depende de la cantidad de elemento seleccionado, si tengo 500 elementos seleccionado por cada elemento envio datos cada 5seg, entonces si son 500x5 = 2500 datos que recibe en un lapso de 0-5 seg (porque no se envia todos los datos al mismo segundo)**, esa actualización masiva de datos pienso que hace que en dispositivo movil se ponga lenta la aplicación, porque en otros módulos que he desarrollado que no tiene esa cantidad de actualizacion de datos por socket, la aplicación es bien fluida

**¿que solución he implementado?**

Investigando un poco encontre " trackby angular" utilizandolo de esta forma:

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let ob of objetos; trackBy: trackByFn">{{ob.tiempo}}<mat-list-item>
```

y en el archivo .ts

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; // or item.id
}
```

Pero al parecer no ha cambiado el comportamiento cuando selecciono menos de 30 registro la aplicación, es fluida y rapida(movil) y cuando selecciono unos 500 se nota la diferencia que se pone un poco mas lenta, repito, la cantidad de veces que actualizó el array this.objetos es bastante exigente y pienso que esa es la razon por la cual se pone lenta, he tratado de optimizarlo y buscar manera de solucionarlo pero no he hayado forma.

**¿de qué forma puedo optimizar la actualización de datos**

¿se podrá renderizar solo lo que está viendo en pantalla en ese momento el usuario? es decir en movil se pueden visualizar uno 7 elementos y los otros 493 elementos estan ocultos(hasta que haga scroll)

Comment: Solo quieres actualiz el tiempo?

Comment: Posiblemente tu problema se deba al renderizado del html. Muestras 500 lineas?. Si es asi, lo que puedes hacer (y que mejorara mucho el rendimiento) es solo renderizar algunos pocos (maximo 30, como dices), despues, mostrar un paginador (con los datos en memoria) para los demas.

Comment: @TomaszVizaint, actualizo con exito el tiempo, con angular si cambio un valor en el archivo .ts me lo cambia en la vista, de eso ya no tengo ningun problema lo que pasa es que la cantidad de veces a actualizar los datos por socket siento que hace que renderize la vista y hace que se ponga lenta la aplicación.

Comment: @Legna tiene sentido tu sugerencia, solo renderizar unos cuantos registro, el problema que no puedo utilizar paginator por la forma de la app tiene que se una lista sin paginator, ¿se puede renderizar solo los elementos que estan en la vista (antes de hacer scroll) y si hace scroll hacia abajo pues comenzar actualizar datos segun vaya viniendo del socket y que corresponda al id del elemento.?

Comment: @Legna perdón no contesté tu pregunta: SI si muestro 500 registro es lo que se nesesita para algunos usuario ver esos 500 elementos y tengo un filtro para buscar (cosa que no es el caso del problema pero lo comento que lo tengo) y cuando hago scroll se pone lenta en el movil. y sin son unos 10 elemento es bien fluida

Comment: @Kevin Castellano puede que no me explice bien, por lo que veo en tu lista supongo que tienes una funcion que comprueba cada cierto tiempo cuando se hizo el cambio, Si esto es cierto, pruba mostral la lista sin esta funcion, y dime si tu aplicacion va mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si estas usando angular material, te recomiendo que revises el cdkScrollable, el cual te permite cargar solo los elementos que se muestran en pantalla.

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="500">
  <mat-list-item *cdkVirtualFor="let ob of objetos">{{ob.tiempo}}<mat-list-item>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Recuerda importar el módulo en tu app.

```
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ScrollingModule] 
})
```

También te recomiendo utilizar la estrategia OnPush, de esta manera evitas actualizar todo el componente automáticamente y solo actualizará la información cuando lo mandes llamar.

Documentación de [changeDetection](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#usage-notes).

Documentación de [cdkScrollable](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/examples).

Comment: Muchisima gracias eso resolvió mi problema, ya que no renderizó todos los cambios en mi lista (500 elementos) sino solo los que estan visible, lo probé en dispositivos movil y si se nota la gran diferencia no se pone lenta, por el momento he utilizado  cdkScrollable. luego estudiaré a profundidad changeDetection. para tratar de optimizar mas mi código.